# Find location to override PC by stack frame with stackoverflow

Tags: ida, buffer-overflow, stack

I have stackoverflow in MIPS arch (without ASLR/canary)

In Ida I see that the buffer that has the overflow located in SP+200

In the beginning if function I can see the stack size because I see the command

```
addiu $sp, -4000
```

So I guess the stack frame on this function is 4000

If I want to override the PC register (when the function is return) , should I need to write to buffer 4000 (stack frame) -200(location of buffer in stack) ? Because the address is decrement is stack?